# SQL Query IF Statment

Tags: sql

Im trying to add a if else type function in the below sql query

```
SELECT        OEEL.invoicedt, UCASE(OEEL.whse) AS Whse, OEEL.orderno, OEEL.ordersuf, OEEL.custno, UCASE(OEEL.shipto) AS Shipto, UCASE(OEEL.slsrepin) AS Slsrepin, 
                     UCASE(OEEL.slsrepout) AS Slsrepout, OEEL.returnfl, OEEL.netamt, OEEL.wodiscamt, OEEL.discamtoth, OEEL.qtyship, OEEL.commcost, ICSS.csunperstk, UCASE(ICSD.name) AS Name, 
                     UCASE(ICSD.region) AS Region, UCASE(OEEL.prodcat) AS Prodcat, UCASE(SASTA.descrip) AS Descrip, UCASE(OEEL.transtype) AS Transtype, UCASE(ARSS.user2) AS User2, 
                     OEEL.transdt, ICSS.transdt AS "ICSS.Transdt", ICSD.transdt AS "ICSD.Transdt", SASTA.transdt AS "SASTA.Transdt", ARSS.transdt AS "ARSS.Transdt", { fn CURDATE() } AS CURDATE1, { fn CURTIME() } AS CURTIME2, 
                     OEEL.lineno

FROM            { oj { oj { oj { oj PUB.oeel OEEL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.icss ICSS ON OEEL.cono = ICSS.cono AND OEEL.shipprod = ICSS.prod AND OEEL.icspecrecno = ICSS.icspecrecno } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.icsd ICSD ON OEEL.cono = ICSD.cono AND OEEL.whse = ICSD.whse } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.sasta SASTA ON OEEL.cono = SASTA.cono AND OEEL.prodcat = SASTA.codeval } LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PUB.arss ARSS ON OEEL.cono = ARSS.cono AND OEEL.custno = ARSS.custno AND OEEL.shipto = ARSS.shipto }


WHERE        (OEEL.cono = 1) AND (OEEL.invoicedt BETWEEN { d '2014-06-02' } AND { d '2014-06-03' }) AND (SASTA.codeiden IN ('C', 'c')) 


ORDER By  OEEL.custno, OEEL.shipto, OEEL.prodcat
```

i would the if to be something like

```
if OEEL.returnfl = False THEN (OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth) AS "SALES"
Else (-1*(OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth)) AS "SALES"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add CASE Statement in your query

```
CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = 'False' THEN (OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth) ELSE (-1*(OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth)) END AS "SALES"
```